# Cannot find Matlab Video file

Tags: image, matlab, video, avi

I'm only showing a section of my code here because the whole thing is a few hundred lines. aviFileName is defined above as a string. X is a uint16 image. Matlab runs fine and returns no errors, but I cannot find this video file. It is not in the folder where the code is. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
writerObj = VideoWriter(aviFileName);
open(writerObj)
img=X;
img=im2uint8(img);
writeVideo(writerObj,img);
close(writerObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably forgot to add `close(writeObj)` at the end... you see if you `open(...` you sometimes need to `close(...` after the code ends, otherwise a file cannot be finalized.

### Edit:

When I run this minimal code, I do see the avi file created in the folder of the code:

```
aviFileName='test'
writerObj = VideoWriter(aviFileName);
open(writerObj)
img=rand(256);
img=im2uint8(img);
writeVideo(writerObj,img);
close(writerObj);
```

Comment: I actually did have it, sorry I should have included that line

Comment: well? was it the filename, or you just didn't find the avi file because your folder was too cluttered :-) ?

Comment: Okay so it turns out my avi file was being saved in the folder where I took the picture from because I cd'd there at the beginning of the code =P sorry for the trouble